# Casting class into a struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have this :

```
class masterStruct {

public:

int counter; 
bool synchronized;
std::string slaveIDs[3];

void test() { counter = 0; }

}
```

It's defined in my class like this:

```
class MasterInterface {

public:
  struct masterStruct masStruct;

}
```

And I use masStruct in C-style callback functions.

My question is : What happens to the test() function? I know struct and class are essentially the same with class default member variable set to private. Why does c++ allow casting class to struct in this case, where the test() function seems to be no longer valid?

Comment: I see no casts, and why would `test()` be no longer valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between `class` and `struct` is that, in the definition of the type, the default access level is `private` or `public` respectively. Otherwise, and in other contexts (such as this one), they are identical.

`class masterStruct` and `struct masterStruct` are two names for the same type. There's no casting because there's only one type. C++ allows the keywords to be used interchangeably because the default access level is no more than a minor implementation detail within the definition.

C++ class types (declared with `class` or `struct`) can be accessed from C functions as long as certain C++ features can't be used. `virtual` functions, mixed access protection for members, etc. can affect the layout of the members in memory, so the C compiler won't be able to find them. "POD" (plain old data) classes are a slight superset of what C will understand, because certain kinds of single inheritance are also permitted.

Nonstatic member functions don't add anything to a class in memory, so they don't affect its layout. They're just ordinary functions with special rules for passing an additional argument which implements `this`. C doesn't need to know about them, so you can safely `#ifndef __cplusplus` them out.

However, it doesn't sound like you're using `masterStruct` from C code at all, but you're only passing a `void*` through a C library and back to yourself. In this case, POD-ness doesn't make a difference either. The `void*` value is just a scalar value, and it will be the same when you pass it and when you get it back. It could point to anything, or to nothing; it doesn't matter.

Comment: So technically, when I pass the class into a callback function via a void* datapointer, and cast it like this: masterStruct* mStruct = (masterStruct*) data , I can do mStruct->test() ?

Comment: @lppier It depends on which language you use. In C++, you can; In C API, you can't.

Comment: @EricZ Thanks for the clarification. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Why does c++ allow casting class to struct in this case, where the test() function
seems to be no longer valid?
```

In C++, `struct` can also have functions. So you can cast a `class` object to an object of the according `struct`, and access the member functions via that `struct` object. Note that the access specifiers(`public`, `private`, or `protected`) in the original `class` definition determines how the member functions are accessed. Casting to `struct` doesn't redefine those functions as `public`, which you may wonder.

I guess your real question is why a C++ `struct`(or `class` as in your original question) can be passed to a C API where there is no member function concept in the language?

This is doable due to Plain Old Data(POD) types support in C++. POD objects in C++ are interchangable with C. That's why you can pass it to C API. In short, A POD type is a `struct` or `class` without user-defined constructors, destructors and virtual member functions, which is exactly your case. For a detailed discussion, refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).